# The Executioner Conundrum

Tags: probability

You are a military executioner tasked with eliminating some of the most dangerous criminals on Earth. You are handed 100 such criminals for immediate termination. However, just as you are about to execute them, word comes from a highly reliable source that 1 of the 100 is not a criminal at all. In fact he is one of the greatest examples of humanity and killing him will be a great loss to us all. You are also told that since he finds killing a grotesque and unfitting punishment, he refuses to identify himself in a hope for bringing amnesty to the others and stopping the executions.

Your commanding officer however, says that you should then kill half of the prisoners and release the rest. He thinks based on his math knowledge that you have a very low chance of killing the innocent person if you kill 50% of the prisoners.

However, while you are not a math whiz it seems like there is a great chance to kill the innocent person even if you kill a handful of people. If only you knew more math, you could prove to your commanding officer that killing just a few would already result in a very high chance of killing the innocent person and hopefully you can convince him of the futility of the executions. In your long career as an executioner you begin to wonder how many times an innocent was handed down and now that you know with certainty there is such a person in danger you would rather not have it on your conscience.

Summary of problem:

Your goal is to convince your superior to avoid the executions. To do this show that with every sequential killing the chance that you "miss" the innocent person decreases and the chance that you kill them increases, similar to the chance of avoiding a 6 on a dice decreases with each roll.

You post on Mathematics Stack Exchange and hope for the best!

(What... He's got an iPhone. I never said he's in the stone ages)

Comment: Edited. But this was about some ingenious thinking as well. You want to present the data in a way that makes the commanding officer change his mind. It was not that abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you pick $n$ people out of $100$. There is a $\frac{n}{100}$ probability that the good person is in the set of $n$ people and thus a $\frac{n}{100}$ probability that the good person will be killed.

This is a classic example of a very long word problem with lots of extraneous information that has an extremely simple solution because it's a very simple problem, just with a lot of other details. Don't let these other details distract you from what the relevant information is: How many people you pick, how many people there are, and how many good people there are.

---

Here is an example with $n=3$.

- First, you kill one person. The probability that you kill the good person is $\frac 1{100}$.
- - Now, the probability that this doesn't happen is $\frac{99}{100}$, so anything after this needs to be multiplied by that factor. If you kill another person, the probability that you kill the good person is now $\frac{1}{99}$.
- - - Now, the probability that this doesn't happen is $\frac{98}{99}$, so anything after this needs to be multiplied by that factor. If you kill another person, the probability that you kill the good person is now $\frac{1}{98}$.

Now, if you follow this tree and add the cases while multiplying the conditions, we get:
$$\frac{1}{100}+\frac{99}{100}\left(\frac{1}{99}+\frac{98}{99}\cdot \frac{1}{98}\right)=\frac{3}{100}$$

Comment: Ok let me clarify. Imagine that he kills them one at a time. With each killing the probablity that the innocent person is killed increases. After killing how many people is the probability over 90% or "almost certain"

Comment: @Harry It's still $\frac{n}{100}$, regardless of whether or not they kill them all at once or in succession, because they picked a set of $n$ people to be killed. The probability is over $90\%$ at $n=91$.

Comment: It does not make sense to me. This problem is like saying you have a 1 in 100 chance to hit number 7 on roulette. How many times in a row can you miss?

Comment: @Harry If you are on number 7, then you know that you have already missed six other rolls, so the probability is $\frac{1}{96}$. What you have to realize, though, is that there is a condition of you missing those six rolls first, so if you look at it from the beginning, the condition of you missing those six rolls times the probability that you miss the seventh is $\frac{1}{100}$. I've edited my answer above to show you how these conditions affect this problem.

Comment: (Also, the first probability in the above comment should be $\frac{1}{94}$.)

Answer (score 2):

You announce that you will only kill 1 of the hundred, and then ask for a volunteer.

You let the volunteer go (he is the good guy), and execute the 99 others.

Comment: I love how you think.